# How to set compiler flags per Build type?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wno-unused-function)
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
  list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wno-unused-function)
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Intel")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
  list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS /WX /W4 /wd4505 /permissive- /analyze:external- /external:anglebrackets /external:W0 /wd4251 /Zc:preprocessor /Zc:__cplusplus /Zc:char8_t Yes /Zc:rvalueCast)
  add_compile_definitions(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE /fp:fast /GL /MP /Gw /GR- /Oy /Ot /Oi)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO /fp:fast /GL /MP /Gw /GR- /Oy /Ot /Oi)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL /fp:fast /GL /MP /Gw /GR- /Oy /Ot /Oi)
endif()
```

However, when the Visual Studio Solution is generated, it does not have any of these flags:

[image]

Only the default flags seems to be populated.

Comment: Is definition of macro `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` actually added to the Visual Studio solution? If not, then it seems your **branch is not executed** for some reason. When debug it is a good approach to remove (temporary) from the code all branching which is not related to the problem.

Comment: @Tsyvarev _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS is defined in the solution

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to not use `list(APPEND ..)` but `string(APPEND ...)`:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wno-unused-function")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -Wextra -Wno-unused-function")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Intel")
elseif (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " /WX /W4 /wd4505 /permissive- /analyze:external- /external:anglebrackets /external:W0 /wd4251 /Zc:preprocessor /Zc:__cplusplus /Zc:char8_t Yes /Zc:rvalueCast")
  add_compile_definitions(_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS)
  string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE " /fp:fast /GL /MP /Gw /GR- /Oy /Ot /Oi")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO " /fp:fast /GL /MP /Gw /GR- /Oy /Ot /Oi")
  string(APPEND CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL " /fp:fast /GL /MP /Gw /GR- /Oy /Ot /Oi")
endif()
```